# ColdFusion Webservice to show database schema

Tags: sql-server, web-services, security, coldfusion

I want to make a web service to some details on the underlying database.

```
<cffunction name="getDBSchema" output="false" returnType="query" access="remote">


<cfquery name="local.qryPlugin" cachedwithin="#CreateTimeSpan(1,0,0,0)#">
    SELECT column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length, kcu.TABLE_SCHEMA, 
    kcu.table_name,ordinal_position, is_nullable 
    FROM information_schema.COLUMNS kcu
    ORDER BY table_name, ordinal_position
</cfquery>

<cfreturn local.qryPlugin>
```

I can concerned that even with the cachedwithin set to one day, I still might be hitting the db too hard. I am also concerned I am introducing a vulnerablity. The DB schema information itself is not sensitive information

Comment: queries are no big deal from a "hitting the database" perspective.  making your db design available to hackers is a big deal.  why do you want to do this at all?

Comment: I want to provide a quick up to date documentation of the internal DBs schema. Although it is not shown, the web service is only accessible via a restricted number of IPs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked two specific questions - one, is caching for a day enough, and two, is this a security issue.

1) Caching for a day seems like it would be *more* than enough. That's an incredibly long cache. Not sure why you wouldn't think it would be enough, but it seems great to me.

2) I am NOT a security expert. You mentioned this is accessible via internal IPs only, so that's probably good enough, but you may want to ask yourself why you are sharing these details in general? Do you users really need this info?

Finally - don't forget ColdFusion has a [<cfdbinfo>](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_d-e_01.html) tag that does this. Your code works, obviously, but I'm just sharing that in case you didn't know.

Comment: I like that <cfdbinfo> pulls all the data I need and will work on day db